# Displaying NSImage beyond limits of view

Tags: macos, appkit

I'm rather new to AppKit programming and OS X programming in general so forgive me if this is a n00b question.  I would like to make a windowless app which does nothing but take an image and animate it across the user's screen.  If I bound myself to the window limits of my app this is easy to accomplish.  How to I animate things if I want to go beyond my window/view limits?

Answer (score 0):

You can't literally draw outside your window, but you can make your window borderless, transparent, and cover the whole screen or screens.

Comment: If "Displays have separate Spaces" is enabled, you can't make a window span multiple screens. You have to use multiple windows, one per screen. And then you would have to replicate the image view into all of them and get the relative position right and maybe synchronize the movement (by bracketing the change in position in all the windows with disable/enable screen updates calls).